# Chef on AWS instance with different terminologies

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have this AWS instance running chef-server, workstation,client, user and knife. 
But as everything is installed on the same instance, I am getting more and more confused about the component that I just installed after the installation process.

So far I know that 'knife' runs on the workstation.

Please Chef experts help me understand and answer the questions I have;

1) After I used the command 'knife configure -i', created 2 different clients chef webadmin-ui and chef-validator.

But can you please explain me what is a client and a user ?

When we say 'client' / 'user' does that mean the same term we use for chef-client that installs dependencies on a node ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Client and User are very close to the same thing. They both have a public RSA key stored on the Chef Server which is used for API access. A user is a client plus a password to log in to the web interface if you are using that. Users can also join more than one organization, while clients only live in a single org. Chef uses RSA signatures for API authentication so the Client and User records are similar to a token or key to control API access, and then they are used by the ACL system to control what API calls are allowed.

None of this is related to `chef-client`, which is also sometimes called "the Client" when talking about a client/server setup. `chef-client` is the agent program which runs your Chef recipes.

Comment: I had forgotten the fact that users can cross organisations. It does appear that the concept of a "user" was bolted on later. Confusing to new users, good answer

Comment: Kind of, it was definitely not the most elegant solution. In the very early days clients used OpenID instead of RSA keys, and so there wasn't a need for a separate users construct. Then everyone convinced the devs that server-to-server OpenID was terrrrrrrrible (which it was), so here we are.

Answer (score 1):

Chef has a few confusing concepts.

[Clients](http://docs.chef.io/server_manage_clients.html)

> An API client is any machine that has permission to use the Chef
>   server API to communicate with the Chef server. An API client is
>   typically a node (on which the chef-client runs) or a workstation (on
>   which knife runs), but can also be any other machine configured to use
>   the Chef server API.

[Nodes](http://docs.chef.io/server_manage_nodes.html)

> A node is any physical, virtual, or cloud machine that is configured
>   to be maintained by a chef-client.

[Users](http://docs.chef.io/server_orgs.html)

> A user is any non-administrator human being who will manage data that
>   is uploaded to the Chef server from a workstation or who will log on
>   to the Chef Manage web user interface. The Chef server includes a
>   single default user that is defined during setup and is automatically
>   assigned to the admins group

My advice is not to get too hung up on the difference between clients and users. Yes they appear to be the same, however, the latter is designed to support human beings.